# diferencia entre .classList y .class

Tags: javascript, css3

Este codigo es un progress-step para que se quede marcado voy eliminando la clase btn-default e insertando la clase btn-primary pero cuando agrego la clase porque me muestra undefined? y cuando usao .class="btn-primary" me muestra el nombre de la clase, y otra duda por que mostrandome undefined aun asi funciona?

```js
var h1 = document.querySelectorAll(".stepwizard-row > .stepwizard-step >.btn");

for (h of h1) {
    h.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    var h2 = document.querySelectorAll(".stepwizard-row > .stepwizard-step >.btn");
    for (hh of h2) {
      hh.classList.remove('btn-primary');
    }
        var hp = evt.target;
        hp.classList.remove('btn-default');
        hp.classList.add('btn-primary');
       // hp.class='btn-primary';
        console.log("su clase es ", hp.className);
    });
}
```

```css
body{margin:40px;}

.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;    
}

.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.stepwizard {
    display: table;     
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
    
}

.stepwizard-step {    
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


 <div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row">
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="uno" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</button>
            <p>Registro #1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="dos" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">2</button>
            <p>Registro #2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <button id="tres" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle">3</button>
            <p>Registro #3</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Es un error tipográfico. Las clases CSS las puedes ver en los atributos `className` o `classList` **no** en `class` (es una palabra reservada paa creación de "clases").

Comment: @Guz mi codigo usa classList y me muestra undefined

Comment: Te muestra undefined aquí: `console.log("su clase es ", hp.class);` por la razón que ya te mencioné: **no existe un atributo** `.class` **en HTMLElement**.

Comment: @Guz cierto gracias, otra cosa por que no muestra este codigo igual a http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/0B9ld si de ahi lo copie(pero no el js)

Comment: No puedo ver ese snippet, no tengo cuenta en bootsnipp ;) Si es una duda referente a programación, puedes hacer una nueva pregunta.

Comment: @Guz http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/process-steps actualice el link

Comment: Añade estas reglas a los botones: `border-radius: 100%`, `line-height: 30px` y `padding: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

> **No existe** el atributo `.class` en [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

La palabra reservada `class` se usa para creación de "clases" en JavaScript; no hay atributo con ese nombre en ningún elemento. Por otro lado, el atributo classlist es un [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) y como es obvio tiene los métodos de ésta interface, como son:

- add
- remove
- toggle
- replace

Y varios métodos más que puedes consultar en la documentación.